# No images found when using image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to load the data using dataset_from_directory in tensorflow.It not detecting any images. I only have one class.

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

pixel_rows = 3402
pixel_cols = 3401

image_size = (pixel_cols, pixel_rows)
batch_size = 32

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory( 'D:\\UAV\\Train\\Input',
                                              class_names=None,
                                              labels = None,
                                              image_size=image_size,
                                              color_mode='rgb',
                                              seed = 42)
```

ERROR message:
Found 0 files belonging to 1 classes.

Comment: There is a folder train and inside that there are the images

Comment: yes,it is like the e.g

Comment: What image formats and filename do you have?

Comment: tif format and files names are 1,1.1,1.2.......500

Comment: TIFF images are not supported, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory , it says "Supported image formats: jpeg, png, bmp, gif. Animated gifs are truncated to the first frame."

Comment: I can use Imagedatagenerator to load the data but this result in an error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594832/y-argument-is-not-supported-when-using-keras-utils-sequence-as-input

Comment: what are the file extensions in the directory? can you read this directory with pure python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated the issue using given code. This is importing all `.jpeg` images successfully.

As mentioned `@Dr. Snoopy`
, There could be problem with images type. You can refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) for more details.

As being said here:

```
`Supported image formats: jpeg, png, bmp, gif. Animated gifs are truncated to the first frame`.
```

Comment: the issue was the file format been "TIFF". i created a custom generator to pass the data