# `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using supervised learning. I am not classifying anything I am trying to see if i can change the resolution of input by giving high resolution output. I have low resolution input and high resolution output. The output are also images not class names. Should the output be given as a list.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0./255)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0./255)
train_out_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0./255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=0./255)

train_indir = r"D:\\UAV\\Train\\Input"
validation_indir = r"D:\\UAV\\Train\\validation"
output_outdir = r"D:\\UAV\\Train\\Output"

input_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_indir,
        target_size = (3402,3401),#(3402,3401),
        batch_size =32,
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='input') 
valid_gen = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            validation_indir,
            target_size = (3402,3401),  #(3402,3401),
            batch_size =32,
            color_mode='rgb',
            class_mode = 'input')

output_gen = train_out_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        output_outdir,
        target_size = (3402,3401),#(3402,3401),
        batch_size =32,
        color_mode='rgb',
        class_mode='input')
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(3402,3401,3),
    pooling=None,  
)
for layer in base_model.layers[:]:
    layer.trainable = False
model = Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(Convolution2D(3,9,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(UpSampling2D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Convolution2D(3,9,activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.build((None, 3402, 3401, 3))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(input_gen,output_gen,validation_data = valid_gen,batch_size =32,epochs=100)
```

Comment: What is `train_out_datagen` here? Do you have data in directory structure? If yes, model will understand label so no need to pass the label. Then try as `model.fit(input_gen, validation_data = valid_gen,batch_size =32,epochs=100)`. Thanks!

Comment: The way i am trying to do the training is different. I had solved the issue by creating a custom generator that only passes images and not the label in both input and output